# Getting color code while web scraping using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup in Python to do web **scraping**. The text on the website has the names written in red font color, and I need to have the color codes. I am using the text on the website as my training data for NER (only for proper names). How can I get the color code using beautifulsoup? At the moment my code looks like this.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

req = requests.get('https://www.islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&idfrom=1&idto=272&bk_no=86&ID=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Just added the URL. The website is in Arabic.

Comment: The text is in arabic. Do you need to extract the text that is in red color?

Comment: I need to extract the main text in the website, and I need to extract everything in those couple of paragraphs. I just need for the red segments to have some sort of a tag so that I can then manually turn the entirety of the text into my training data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right. This script will get all text from the main body without any tags. Only red text portions are enclosed in `<TAG>`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString


url = "https://www.islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&idfrom=1&idto=272&bk_no=86&ID=2"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

body = soup.select_one("#pagebody")
for tag in body.find_all(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "span" and "none" in tag.get("style", "")
):
    tag.extract()

for tag in body.select(":not(.names)"):
    tag.unwrap()

out = []
for c in body.contents:
    if isinstance(c, NavigableString):
        c = c.strip()
        if c:
            out.append(c)
    else:
        out.append("<TAG>{}</TAG>".format(c.get_text(strip=True)))

print(" ".join(out))
```

Prints:

```
1 [ ص: 7 ] بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم وصلى الله على سيدنا محمد وآله وصحبه وسلم أخبرنا الإمام الحافظ <TAG>أبو القاسم سليمان بن أحمد بن أيوب اللخمي الطبراني</TAG> - رحمه الله - قال : هذا أول كتاب فوائد مشائخي الذين كت
بت عنهم بالأمصار ، خرجت عن كل واحد منهم حديثا واحدا وجعلت أسماءهم على حروف المعجم . باب الألف من اسمه أحمد حدثنا <TAG>أحمد بن عبد الوهاب بن نجدة الحوطي أبو عبد الله</TAG> بمدينة جبلة سنة تسع وسبعين ومائتين ، حدث
نا جنادة بن مروان الأزدي [ ص: 8 ] الحمصي ، حدثنا <TAG>مبارك بن فضالة</TAG> ، عن الحسن ، عن <TAG>أنس بن مالك</TAG> - رضي الله عنه - قال : قال رسول الله - صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم - : " سألت ربي - عز وجل - ثلاث خصا
ل فأعطاني اثنتين ومنعني واحدة ، سألته أن لا يسلط على أمتي عدوا من غيرهم فأعطانيها ، وسألته أن لا يقتل أمتي بالسنة فأعطانيها ، وسألته أن لا يلبسهم شيعا فأبى علي " . لم يروه عن <TAG>مبارك بن فضالة</TAG> إلا جنادة .
```

Comment: Great. This is the exact thing I was looking for!